# What is the best way to forward a single qmail alias to /dev/null?

Tags: unix, system-administration, qmail

I would like to trash the mail received by a single qmail alias.  I don't want any mail delivery errors, and I want qmail to be happy about having delivered the mail.

How can I do this, preferably without adding another local email account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alias with only a comment and no delivery instructions, like:

```
echo "# drop all messages on the floor" > ~alias/.qmail-devnull
```

Replace "devnull" with whatever alias name you need of course.

Answer (score 2):

Create an alias by creating a file /var/qmail/aliases/.qmail-*blackhole* with this content:

```
|cat >/dev/null
```

Then redirect whatever you want to this ‘blackhole’ alias (or use whatever you want in place of ‘blackhole’). Merely using /dev/null won’t work (`Unable_to_write_/dev/null`).

The messages will still be logged, however. Though it’s more of a feature than a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A meta-question: why would this get rated down?  Is it not appropriate for the site?

Comment: Strictly speaking the site is for programming related questions - however it seems to be a law unto itself right now (with regards to downvoting)...